# How should I transition my Thanksgiving Cactus to artificial indoor light?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, holiday-cactus

I have a Thanksgiving Cactus that is getting covered in flower buds but it is getting near the frost date. This plant was outdoors most of the year this year and it has grown like crazy. How do I keep it from dropping its flower buds in the transition from an outside shade location with a 45-75F temperature range, to an indoor location with fluorescent lighting?

Edit: It already has the flowers. My problem is the transition from outside to indoors.

Comment: Hybrid of Schlumbergera truncata - tropical epiphyte. Very closely related to the Christmas cactus. Also looks similar to the Easter Cactus but that is Rhipsalidopsis. All three are rainforest epiphytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/thanksgiving-cactus.html) gives the following temperature information when flowers are setting:

> Temperature: To set flower buds, the plant needs cool 60-65°F/16-18°C
>   days and 45-55°F/7-13°C nights. Once buds set, 70-75°F/21-24°C days
>   and 60-70°F/16-21°C nights.

Comment: The little I know about holiday cacti (which isn't a lot), is they require approx 6 weeks of either: 12 to 13 hours of total darkness (similar to poinsettias) or constantly cool temperatures 55°F (13°C) being ideal, for buds/flowers to set. When temperatures drop below 50°F (10°C) the risk of damaging the buds greatly increase...

Comment: Last year it made a lot less flower buds, but it was in 24 hour fluorescent light then in seventy degrees. This year the plant has a very  wide temperature range, With only sunlight.

Comment: It already has flower buds. I don't need to know how to force flowers.